# Sparse matrices that represent common stencil operations

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question!

Is there a data set such as the [University of Florida Sparse Matrix Collection](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/matrices/) which  is produced from stencil operations?

Or is there a way to generate such sparse matrices, maybe using Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for matrices that come from, e.g., finite differences applied to a PDE.

You may try the [matrix market](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/). There you can search for matrices from common PDE applications.

In Matlab there is the function [del2](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/del2.html) that returns a matrix representing a discrete Laplace operator.

Comment: I am really not sure what is the origin of stencil operations!

Comment: In the field of numerical analysis, I know the stencil as an illustration of the geometric arrangement of the nodes that are used to approximate a differential operator e.g. via finite differences. See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_(numerical_analysis)) although it is not very extensive.